# Does MySQL automatically use the coalesce function during a join between tables?

Tags: mysql, join, coalesce

During a table join, when does MySQL use this function?

> The single result column that replaces two common columns is defined
> using the coalesce operation. That is, for two t1.a and t2.a the
> resulting single join column a is defined as a = COALESCE(t1.a, t2.a),
> where:
>
> ```
> COALESCE(x, y) = (CASE WHEN x IS NOT NULL THEN x ELSE y END)
> ```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html

I know what the function does, but I want to know when it is used during the `join` operation. This just makes no sense to me! Can someone show me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is in reference to redundant column elimination during natural join and join with using. Describing how the columns are excluded from display.

The order of operation is described above the section you referenced.

> - First, coalesced common columns of the two joined tables, in the    order in which they occur in the first table
> - Second, columns unique to the first table, in order in which they    occur in that table
> - Third, columns unique to the second table, in order in which they    occur in that table

Example

t1

```
| a | b | c |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
```

t2

```
| a | b | d |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
```

The join with using

```
SELECT * FROM t1 JOIN t2 USING (b);
```

Would result in, `t1.b` being coalesced (due to `USING`), followed by the columns unique to the first table, followed by those in the second table.

```
| b | a | c | a | d |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
```

Whereas a natural join

```
SELECT * FROM t1 NATURAL JOIN t2;
```

Would result in, the `t1` columns (or rather common columns from both tables) being coalesced, followed by the unique columns of the first table, followed by those in the second table.

```
| a | b | c | d |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
```

Comment: But the function COALESCE(x,y) would be useful only in cases that we got NULL arguments. So in your example, what would happen if column b from your first table got a NULL value? COALESCE(NULL,y) ? A inner join would exclude this row from result set. But a left join would return it with NULL and not 'y' value.

Comment: Correct, which is why I noted the context of `NATURAL JOIN` and `JOIN USING` and how it removes redundant columns (`COALESCE`). The MySQL documentation also states that `If the join operation is any other join, the result columns of the join consist of the concatenation of all columns of the joined tables.` Along with the explanation of  `With an inner join, COALESCE(a.c1, b.c1) is the same as either a.c1 or b.c1 because both columns will have the same value. With an outer join (such as LEFT JOIN), one of the two columns can be NULL`

Comment: As for in my example, if one of the records for `b` were `NULL` no results would be retrieved. This is because the criteria for the join is not met.

Comment: So the function COALESCE(x,y) is useful only in outer joins, when a row from the first the table does not match any row from second table, and the column list used for join condition (USING or NATURAL clause) use that function to determine which column value to choose? Is that right? or am i missing something?

Comment: In-effect yes, but they are only using `COALESCE` to "describe" how the redundant rows are excluded from the `SELECT *` statement of those join types. As they are truly redundant. Given `SELECT t1.b, t2.b FROM t1 JOIN t2 USING(b)` Would return the `b` column from both tables, as they are no longer redundant, despite having identical column names and values. So the term "useful" is not really applicable. It would be more appropriate to say, redundant columns have "COALESCE" applied to them when the columns are **implicitly** common among the joined tables.

Comment: Oh, thanks! I think a better example would be using FULL OUTER JOIN. Where columns from both tables can be NULL. In mysql we don't have FULL OUTER JOIN but we can simulate it, even so, we have to call the function COALESCE(x,y) manually if we want to exclude redundant columns! i think i get it now! Thanks for the help!